# How can I use the facebook connect api for the iphone to to invite friends to an application or send a message

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook

In my iPhone application, I wanted to add the function of signing into Facebook and letting a friend know about the app. I know how to sign in and get the friends list, but I cannot find a good way of inviting a friend. So far, I haven't been able to come up with a way to invite a friend (I don't think one can with the iphone facebook sdk yet) or send a message to the inbox. Is there a way to do either of these? If not are there any better options I haven't thought of? Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

checkout this tutorial. i used it to get the facebook header files sorted out. Once thats done, everything should be in place for you to send a message easily :

http://www.mobileorchard.com/marketing-in-code-part-2-setting-a-users-status-in-facebook-from-an-iphone-app-a-tutorial/

Comment: You can post a facebook status, it is so easy. The question asked about how you send a message to the user's inbox, which I don't find a solution yet

Comment: Sounds like facebook is explicitly blocking that to prevent spamming inboxes. I might be wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

check out [This post](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/213).it shows what camn we do with facebook api